# Custom BaseAdapter wont add new Data - Android

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

I have a custom baseadapter that creates comment boxes. Everything works great on it until I want to add data. When I try to add the data it deletes the previous data and adds the new data. How do I make it so it keeps all the data? Is my Add method incorrect? Here is my baseadapter,

```
class CreateCommentLists extends BaseAdapter{
  Context ctx_invitation;
  String[] listComments;
  String[] listNumbers;
  String[] listUsernames;

  public CreateCommentLists(String[] comments, String[] usernames, String[] numbers, DashboardActivity context)
  {
    super();
    ctx_invitation = context;
    listComments = comments;
    listNumbers = usernames;
    listUsernames = numbers;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    if(null == listComments)
    {
      return 0;
    }   

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listComments.length;
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listComments[position];
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = null;
    try
    {
      String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
      LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)ctx_invitation.getSystemService(inflater);
      v = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

      TextView commentView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listComment);
      TextView NumbersView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listNumber);
      TextView usernamesView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listPostedBy);
      Button usernameButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.listUsernameButton);
      Button numberButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.listNumberButton);

      commentView.setText(listComments[position]);
      NumbersView.setText(listNumbers[position]);
      usernamesView.setText(listUsernames[position]);
      usernameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
          i.putExtra("usernameOfProfile",listUsernames[position]);
          startActivity(i);
          finish();
        }
      });

      numberButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
          i.putExtra("NumberProfile",listNumbers[position]);
          startActivity(i);
          finish();
        }
      });   
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return v;
  }

  public void add(String[] comments, String[] usernames,
                  String[] numbers) {
    listComments = comments;
    listNumbers = usernames;
    listUsernames = numbers;
  }

  public int getCount1() {
    if(null == listComments)
    {
      return 0;
    }   

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listComments.length;
  }

  public Object getItem1(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listComments[position];
  }

  public long getItemId1(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
  }

  public View getView1(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = null;
    try
    {
      String inflater = Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE;
      LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)ctx_invitation.getSystemService(inflater);
      v = li.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);


      TextView commentView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listComment);
      TextView NumbersView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listNumber);
      TextView usernamesView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.listPostedBy);
      Button usernameButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.listUsernameButton);
      Button numberButton = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.listNumberButton);

      commentView.setText(listComments[position]);
      NumbersView.setText(listNumbers[position]);
      usernamesView.setText(listUsernames[position]);

      usernameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
          i.putExtra("usernameOfProfile",listUsernames[position]);
          startActivity(i);
          finish();
        }
      });

      numberButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class);
          i.putExtra("NumberProfile",listNumbers[position]);
          startActivity(i);
          finish();
        }
      });
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return v;
  }
}
```

Setting the adapter:

```
final CreateCommentLists mycmlist = new CreateCommentLists(comments, usernames, numbers, DashboardActivity.this);

lstComments = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

lstComments.setAdapter(mycmlist);
```

This is what how I call the add method,

```
mycmlist.add(comments,usernames,numbers);
mycmlist.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: `it deletes the previous data and adds the new data` What did you expect when giving completely new values to the variables holding your data?

Comment: well how do I correctly use the add method?

Comment: What I would do is make each of these arrays a property of a custom object, then use an `ArrayAdapter <CustomObject>` backed by a `List<CustomnObject>`. That way, you have an expandable list and not this fixed-size array nonsense.

Comment: But I use a asynctask to gather the variables (username, comment, number). The AsyncTask gathers 8 of each variable at a time and stores it into a String[]. So I send the baseadapter multiple variables in a string at once. How can I do that with a List<CustomObject>?

Comment: Well if it gathers 8 of each var, there is nothing stopping you from making 8 `CustomObject`s and add them to a `List` in `doInBackground()`. Then in `onPostExecute` Loop through the List returned from `doInBackground()` and call `add()` (or `addAll()` on new api versions with an `ArrayAdapter`. As I mentioned before, use an `ArrayAdapter`, it's easier.

Comment: To be honest I am new to this and really have no idea where to start with that, could you possible make an example code?

Comment: I could, but the chances of you having more problems with my approach are high since it's quite different than what you have here. Did Miro's answer not work?

Comment: No his did not, but I figure everything else out but what I don't understand is how do I create 8 CustomObjects and add them to a list? I get the looping in onPostExecute but not the doInBackground part

Comment: Something like [this](http://pastebin.com/LaWhA8pC).

Comment: wow thanks for that its helps out a lot, but I am trying to create an ArrayAdapter and it wont let me set it. This code creates an error,

`ListAdapter customAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, List<Item>);`

Comment: `List<Item>` needs to be an actual object, for example, change to new `ArrayList <Item>()`. I can't debug everything, please have a look at tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

In your add method you're setting the arrays to new values `listComments = comments;` That's replacing your old data with the new data.

You could use [System.arrayCopy()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) to resize your listArrays to the new size and append the new items. A much less tedious approach, however, would be to store your arrays as `List<String>`, allowing you to add more items without worrying about resizing lists.

The result would look something like this...

```
public class CommentsAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
private LayoutInflater inflater;

private List<String> comments;
private List<String> numbers;
private List<String> usernames;

public CommentsAdapter(Context context)
{
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    comments = new ArrayList<String>();
    numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    usernames = new ArrayList<String>();
}

public void add(String[] comments, String[] numbers, String[] usernames)
{
    this.comments.addAll(Arrays.asList(comments));
    this.numbers.addAll(Arrays.asList(numbers));
    this.usernames.addAll(Arrays.asList(usernames));

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount()
{
    if (comments == null)
        return 0;

    return comments.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position)
{
    return comments.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position)
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        convertView.setTag(new ViewHolder(convertView));
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    holder.commentView.setText(comments.get(position));
    //Other view bind logic here...

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder
{
    public TextView commentView;
    public TextView numbersView;
    public TextView usernamesView;
    public Button usernameButton;
    public Button numberButton;

    public ViewHolder(View v)
    {
        commentView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listComment);
        numbersView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listNumber);
        usernamesView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.listPostedBy);
        usernameButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.listUsernameButton);
        numberButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.listNumberButton);
    }
}
}
```

I also highly recommend reading this page on the Android Developer's site: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Your current adapter implementation is very inefficient, and that page should help you iron out some kinks.

Comment: Updated answer with an example implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add the `String[]` array to the existing one, instead of replacing it.

Add this function which joins two arrays (Sadly there is no already-implemented method for Java):

```
String[] concat(String[] A, String[] B) {
   String[] C= new String[A.length + B.length];
   System.arraycopy(A, 0, C, 0, A.length);
   System.arraycopy(B, 0, C, A.length, B.length);
   return C;
}
```

*Credits: Sun Forum*

And then change the `add` method to this:

```
public void add(String[] comments, String[] usernames,
                  String[] numbers) {
    listComments = concat(listComments, comments);
    listUsernames = concat(listUsernames, usernames);
    listNumbers = concat(listNumbers, numbers);
}
```

And you had a typo in your code. In the add method, the `listUsernames` and `listNumbers` should be swapped I think.. I fixed it for you.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the typo, but I dont think this fixes my problem.